# TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python

I have looked up similar questions, yet most problems are related to omitting the `self` argument in the `__init__` definition.

Code:

```
class steamurl():

    baseurl = "http://api.steampowered.com/{0}/{1}/{2}/"

    def __init__(self, loc1, loc2, vnum, **options):
        self.loc1 = loc1
        self.loc2 = loc2
        self.vnum = vnum
        self.options = options

optionsdic = {
    'key': 'KEYHERE',
    'game_mode': 'all_pick',
    'min_players': '7'
    }

testurl = steamurl("IDOTA2Match_570", "GetMatchHistory", "v001", optionsdic)
```

However here my code was working fine before I added the "optionsdic" to the class. After adding it I get the type error in the title. Am I using `**kwargs` incorrectly as an argument?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `**` to apply `optionsdic` as keyword arguments:

```
testurl = steamurl("IDOTA2Match_570", "GetMatchHistory", "v001", **optionsdic)
```

otherwise it is just another positional argument passing in a dictionary object.

This mirrors the syntax in the function signature.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to pass the contents of `optionsdic` as separate keyword arguments, you need to use `**` [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
testurl = steamurl("IDOTA2Match_570", "GetMatchHistory", "v001", **optionsdic)
```

Answer (score 5):

You should call using `**`:

```
testurl = steamurl("IDOTA2Match_570", "GetMatchHistory", "v001", optionsdic)
```

This will unpack the dictionary into separate keyword arguments. In `__init__` the keyword arguments will then be packed into a dictionary due to `**options`.